# Known as/to be, reveal as/to be, see as/to be

Tags: word-choice, sentence-construction, sentence-meaning

I am having a hard time differentiating "as" and "to be" when they are used with some verbs. What is the difference between them? I have posted some examples to understand the issue better:

> 1- They soon reveal themselves ***to be*** a persistent threat to his
>   life. (Original one) (https://www.theguardian.com/books/2016/dec/21/y-the-last-man-by-brian-k-vaughan-and-pia-guerra-a-dystopia-built-by-women)
>
> 2- They soon reveal themselves ***as*** a persistent threat to his
>   life.
>
> 3- We know her ***to be*** an honest person. (She is an honest person.)
>
> 4- We know her ***as*** an honest person.
>
> 5- Some women see him ***to be*** the last chance for future
>   generations of humanity; others see him as the last memory of the
>   patriarchy.
>
> 6- Some women see him ***as*** the last chance for future generations
>   of humanity; others see him as the last memory of the patriarchy.
>   (Original one)

Answer (score 2):

The usages are very similar and typically can be used interchangeably, at leas in the three instances you have given.

**However** there is a slight difference.

"To be" puts the focus on ***actions***, while "as" puts the focus on inherent identity.

---

Put into practice for 1-2:

#1 implies (at least to me) that that it is the people's actions that are understood as causing the persistent threat to his life.

#2 implies that the people are identifying with the label of "persistent threat to his life".

In this case, because it is indeed the people's actions that are causing the "threat", #1 seems like the superior choice.

---

#3: implies that "through her actions (that we have observed), we have know she is honest"

#4: implies that you would label this person as an "honest person", that may be from what other people have told you/what you have read. This could also have an interpretation that "we" have only seen the "honest side" of her personality as opposed to other "not-honest sides".

In this case both work and the context can tell you which to choose.

---

Same deal here, #6 makes the most sense because you are connecting "him" with the label "last chance for ..."

Answer (score 2):

In your examples, there's effectively no difference, but there can be.

If someone is known *as* a painter, then painting is what they're famous for; painting is the main thing that comes to most people's minds when they think of that person. On the other hand, if someone is known *to be* a painter, then that fact is confirmed to be true, but it may be obscure knowledge. It's the difference between being a famous artist, and being a famous politician who occasionally paints on the side.

"Seen as/seen to be" can be distinguished in the same way. For a different example, if Katie is *seen as* a liar, then most people believe her to be a liar (regardless of whether or not it's true). If Katie is *seen to be* a liar, then this must be in reference to a specific instance in which she was caught lying.

I can't think of any cases where "reveal" would present a clear distinction, but the same theory underlies it.

Comment: I couldn't understand this example you gave: Being a famous artist (I suppose it is "known as an artist) , being a famous politician who occasionally paints ("Known to be an artist") ?

Comment: Is it correct to call someone "painter" if he/she only paints as a hobby? (I mean she/he is not a proffessional artist.)

Comment: @TalhaÖzden Fair, it might not have been the most natural-sounding example. I wouldn't say it's wrong by default though. Your understanding of the example is correct.